# JSON with swiftyJSON Error

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to get data from my api in JSON with SwiftyJSON, but I get this error from server:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred."}

I want to handle it but I get an error in this part when I want to request json
I just want my do nothing when server respond this result

```
 func parsing(){

        var URLString = server + "api/XXXXXX" + String(nextpage) + "&pagesize=10"
        print(URLString)


       guard let
        URLString1 = URLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
         else {fatalError()}

        let url = NSURL(string: URLString1)!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url)  {(data, response, innerError) in
             if let data = data where innerError == nil {
            let jsonData1 = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) as NSData!
            let readableJson = JSON(data: jsonData1, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.nrows = readableJson.count

                for  var i = 0 ; i < self.nrows ; i++ {

                    var json = readableJson[i]
                    let desc = json["Name"].string as String!
                    let iddesc = json["Id"].intValue//.string as String!
                    let groupName = json["Group_Name"].string as String!
                    let price1 = json["Price"].string as String!
                }
            }
          }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if you guys [know each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799052/swift-google-directions-api-json-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-sub) but you're making the same mistake: you're downloading the data twice! Once with NSURLSession and once with NSData... Fix this first before trying to develop further.

Comment: no I don't know that guy :), but I will try what I state ,thanks

Comment: @EricAya I have omit the second jsonData1 and use data itself, now the error occurring somewhere in the data fields in desc, and it says :fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, do I need to use try catch or guard, I have use them both but again the same error happening